How do I fix this, I was trying to create python virtual environment
After running this command (OS = Windows 11):
virtualenv -p install python venv

I'm getting this error:
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='install'

I had multiple Python versions installed. I deleted them all, reinstalled Python 3.12, and virtualenv package.
But now I am getting the error above while trying to create a virtual Python environment.

virtualenv -p install python venv

Could you share output of this commands:
1.
python --version




python3 --version


Command
virtualenv -p install python venv

is incorrect.
Correct command would look like:
virtualenv -p python venv


Issues with the existing cache and temporary files may be. Try reinstalling it and check configuration issues and check path where it is installed

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
